# Docker run returning "snmpd is neither service nor target!? " while trying to restart it

Tags: docker, snmpd

I am new to Docker. I have tried installing snmpd on opensuse13.2 docker image. Installation was completed. Docker build was executed fine. But when trying to restart or check the status of snmpd service, I am getting below error

> "snmpd is neither service nor target!?"

**My Dockerfile:**

```
FROM opensuse:13.2

RUN zypper update \
   && zypper ar -Gf -n packman http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_13.2/ packman \
   && zypper ar -G http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:perl/openSUSE_13.2/devel:languages:perl.repo \
   && zypper --non-interactive install net-snmp

COPY entrypoint.sh /docker/
RUN chmod 755 /docker/entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/docker/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**entrypoint.sh :**

```
    printf 'rocommunity public 127.0.0.1 \nagentaddress udp:127.0.0.1:161' >> /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf
    service snmpd restart
    service snmpd status
    echo "restarted snmp"
```

**Docker build output:**

```
[root@atvts2508 docker_test]# docker build -t snmp .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  4.608kB
Step 1/5 : FROM opensuse:13.2
 ---> a0ae1667209e
Step 2/5 : RUN zypper update    && zypper ar -Gf -n packman http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/openSUSE_13.2/ packman    && zypper ar -G http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:languages:perl/openSUSE_13.2/devel:languages:perl.repo    && zypper --non-interactive install net-snmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6d2d62d8e3c7
Step 3/5 : COPY entrypoint.sh /docker/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> db5f208d9464
Step 4/5 : RUN chmod 755 /docker/entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 163ab499d864
Step 5/5 : ENTRYPOINT /docker/entrypoint.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 495dd68f290f
Successfully built 495dd68f290f

**Docker run output:**

[root@atvts2508 docker_test]# docker run -it snmp bash
snmpd is neither service nor target!?
snmpd is neither service nor target!?
restarted snmp
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Can someone please help me out here? Thanks in advance.